# Permissions, Groups, and Principle of Least Privilege

Tags: permissions, principle-of-least-privilege

Lets say I have the following setup

- Two teams: `TeamAlice` and `TeamBob`
- A command that requires admin access: `admin_command`
- Two sets of computers: `TeamAlice_Computers` and `TeamBob_Computers`

Only `TeamAlice` has login access to `TeamAlice_Computers`, and only `TeamBob` has login access to `TeamBob_Computers`

Is it acceptable to put `TeamAlice` and `TeamBob` in a security group that gives permission to `admin_command`? or should I instead make 2x security groups, explicitly listing the team / computers?  Are there pros/cons to each?

My gut feel is that having a single security group would make the permissions less cluttered and easier to understand, but that somehow it violates the principle of least privilege.  Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1):

I will use another *principle* to answer your question: use more than one defence line in case one gets broken.

If you can be sure that your login protection is 100% secure, both ways are stricly equivalent: only users from TeamAlice can access machines from TeamAlice_Computers and only those having the admin privilege can use `admin_command` there.

Now if `admin_command` is highly sensitive, I would use two security groups. The rationale is that a weakness in the login system allowing a user from TeamAlice to access a machine in TeamAlice_Computers will not give them admin privileges. It should not be possible, but we all know that many softwares can have security flaws...

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Each approach in this case has own pros and cons.

You don't describe how is the login permissions are given.

One approach can be to define 2 groups:

- "AliceAdmins": This group would contain permissions "AliceLogin" and "admin_command"
- "BobAdmins": This group would contain permissions "BobLogin" and "admin_command"

Thus you can configure each of these groups *independently* on each other. For instance, you can easily add some "admin_command_2" to one group but not to the other. Or you can easily remove "admin_command" from one group but keep it in the other.